# Output number of non-consecutive failures from historical data in Bigquery

Tags: sql, database, datetime, google-bigquery, data-analysis

this is related to my previous scenario.

I have a dataset like this:

```
WITH failure_table AS
  (SELECT 'Andrea' AS name, 'Failure' AS status, '2022-04-28 4:00:00' AS timestamp
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-04-28 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-27 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-04-27 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-26 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-25 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-30 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-29 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-28 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-03-28 4:00:00')
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-15 4:00:00')
```

Aside from outputting the timestamp in which a user first committed a failure, and consecutively commits a failure status every day, leading up to today (2022-04-29), I also want to output the non-consecutive block of days in which Karl or Andrea commits a failure.

In this case, Andrea started failing recently at 2022-04-25 4:00:00 and commits 3 failure blocks (03-15, 03-28 to 03-30, 04-25 to 04-28) while Karl started failing recently at 2022-04-27 4:00:00 and commits 2 failure blocks (03-28, 04-27 to 04-28).

Final output should be

| name | status | started recently failing timestamp | recent days failing | total days failing | total failure blocks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrea | Failure | 2022-04-25 4:00:00 | 4 | 8 | 3 |
| Karl | Failure | 2022-04-27 4:00:00 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

Thank you for those who can help, I really would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at below query although it's not refined yet. Hoping help you find some clue to approach your problem.

1. `failure_blocks` is for figuring out each consecutive failing days.
2. `last_blocks` is for finding last failing block to identify `started_recently_failing_timestamp`
3. Main query generates the expected output from previous CTEs.

```sql
WITH failure_table AS (
  SELECT 'Andrea' AS name, 'Failure' AS status, TIMESTAMP '2022-04-28 4:00:00' AS dt
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-04-28 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-27 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-04-27 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-26 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-04-25 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-30 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-29 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-28 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Karl', 'Failure', '2022-03-28 4:00:00'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Andrea', 'Failure', '2022-03-15 4:00:00'
),
failure_blocks AS (
  SELECT *,
         COUNTIF(diff <> 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS total_failure_blocks,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS total_days_failing,
         SUM(diff - 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt) AS block,
    FROM (
      SELECT name, status, dt, IFNULL(DATE_DIFF(dt, LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt), DAY), 0) AS diff
        FROM failure_table
    )
),
last_blocks AS (
SELECT * EXCEPT(diff, block), 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name, block) AS recent_days_failing,
       FIRST_VALUE(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY name, block ORDER BY dt) AS block_start_dt
  FROM failure_blocks
)
SELECT name, status, 
       MAX(block_start_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS started_recently_failing_timestamp,
       recent_days_failing,
       total_days_failing,
       total_failure_blocks,
  FROM last_blocks 
 WHERE TRUE QUALIFY dt = started_recently_failing_timestamp
;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jaytiger, I ran your sample code but the QUALIFY part presents an error, doesn't that require a GROUP BY or HAVING BY clause right?

Comment: Hi, above query runs with no problem and `QUALIFY` doesn't require anything as you said. Could you show the error message ?

Comment: SQL_ANALYSIS_ERROR: QUALIFY clause must be used in conjunction with WHERE or GROUP BY or HAVING clause

Comment: Above limitation was when `QUALIFY` is in it's preview status. It's weird it still exists . Anyway would you try it again adding `WHERE TRUE` in front of `QUALIFY` keyword ? I'll update it in my answer also.

Comment: It now worked with the WHERE TRUE! Will do some digging and try to incorporate other aspects of our requirements, but this is really a great help for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider also below approach

```
select name, status,
  sum(if(rank = 1, consecutive_days, 0)) as recent_days_failing,
  sum(consecutive_days) as total_days_failing,
  count(block_id) as total_failure_block_ids
from (
  select name, status, block_id, 
    date_diff(max(dt), min(dt), day) + 1 as consecutive_days,
    rank() over(partition by name, status order by block_id) rank
  from (
    select name, status, date(timestamp) dt,
      row_number() over(partition by name, status order by timestamp) + 
      date_diff(current_date, date(timestamp), day) as block_id
    from failure_table
  )
  group by name, status, block_id
)
group by name, status
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail, what if I want to get the recent date that the person has failed leading up to today (started recently failing timestamp), how can I add to that one? I am thinking of date_sub(max(dt), interval sum(if(rank = 1, consecutive_days, 0)) day) but it gives an error.